# How to single out results with soup.find() in Beautifulsoup4 for Python 3.6?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the price of a ticker symbol from a website, and in the inspect tool the stock price looks like it is determined by this line right here:

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="274.9">
```

and my code in python looks like this

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPY:US'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')
price_box = soup.find('meta', {"itemprop" : "price"})
print(price_box)
```

But in the terminal it prints all of the meta content that contains the word "price" in the beginning. Like priceChange, priceCurrency, etc. I just want the results of "price". Also it will display like this:

```
<meta content="274.9" itemprop="price"> <meta content="1.3" itemprop="priceChange"> <meta content="0.475146" itemprop="priceChangePercent"> <meta content="2018-06-04T20:15:05.000Z" itemprop="quoteTime"> <meta content="USD" itemprop="priceCurrency"> </meta></meta></meta></meta></meta>
```

How do I display just the number?

Comment: First, it's not finding all the values, it's finding just the first one, and then treating the others as subtags within that tag. For example, you can `print(price_box['content'])` and you're going to get `274.9`, just as you'd hope.

Comment: @abarnert thank you so much, all that for such an easy fix lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's not actually finding multiple values; the fact that the other `meta` tags have `itemprop`s that start with `price` is purely coincidence. A `find` call always finds only one tag. And, even if you use `find_all`, it will give you a list of that one tag. The problem is that it's a nested tag, which includes all the other ones inside it.

---

If you look at the HTML, this isn't what's actually there. The tags are all self-closed, independent children of the `"schema-org-financial-quote"` `div`'s `itemscope`, not nested within each other.

The problem seems to be that this HTML is invalid, and `html.parser` is guessing at it differently from the way your browser does.

As far as I can tell from glancing at the specs, a `meta` tag in the `body` that provides an `itemprop` for an `itemscope` is not supposed to be closed. But the page has self-closing `meta` tags.

The obvious way a human would read this is to just ignore the closes and treat these as the independent siblings they appear to be. And that's what at least Chrome and Firefox do. (Interestingly, at least in Chrome, self-closing `meta` tags in the `head` are treated differently from self-closing `itemprop` `meta` tags in the `body`, which implies that it may be deliberately working around buggy pages like this.)

But `html.parser` does something different, and instead nests each one inside the previous one.

If I'm right that the HTML is actually invalid, this isn't technically a bug. But it probably would still be better to handle this better. Since Python 2.7/3.2, `html.parser` is supposed to "lenient like a browser", and it's not doing what browsers do here. So, you might want to [search for a bug on this, and file one if it doesn't exist](https://bugs.python.org). (However, even if it does get fixed in, say, Python 3.7.1 or 3.8, that's not going to help when someone runs your code in 3.6.4.)

---

If you can use `lxml` or `html5lib` instead of `html.parser`, that solves your problem—both of them happen to parse these tags the same way Chrome does, which is presumably what you want.

---

However… do you actually need to solve this? If you just want the `content` of the `price` tag, that already works:

```
>>> price_box = soup.find('meta', {"itemprop" : "price"})
>>> print(price_box['content'])
274.9
```